# Jquery Flexslider in Angular

Tags: angularjs, json, flexslider

Our designer has given me jquery flexslider for showing recently viewed items in our project. I need to construct a slider of recently viewed products in angular js, dynamically based on provided flex slider.In my system, recently viewed items are stored as json object( not array).

First of all flexslider is not working, it means sliding feature is not working inside my angular project. I tried to use angular flex slider module from online and tried to iterate my nested object and construct a slider using my data. It is also not working(picture is not showing). My designer asked me to write down a directive, so overall design will not have any problem or any design modification. 
  Can any of you can help me regarding this 
  Jquery flex slider dynamic part inside partial as follows

```
 <<div class="recent_summary clearfix">
                <h2>RECENTLY VIEWED</h2>



                <div class="nav_carousel">
                    <div class="carousel mini_thumb_slider">

                        <ul class="stage_nav">

                          <li ng-repeat="arrObj in recentItems">
                            <div ng-repeat="arrItem in arrObj.timestamp track by $index">
                                <div ng-repeat="(wsitekey,item) in arrItem.sites track by $index">




                                    <div ng-repeat="(prokey,proMd5) in item.add_to_cart track by $index">
                                        <div class="product-image mini">
                                            <div class="p_image_innner">
                                                <img ng-src="{{proMd5.image}}" title="{{proMd5.title}}  by {{item.info.name}}">
                                                <div class="rateit">
                                                    <div class="rateis">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <a class="quick-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#quick-popup" ng-click="set_current_product_pro(proMd5,item,prokey,wsitekey)">+</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="caption"><a ng-click="menuShopApi('',item.info.name)">{{item.info.name}}</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div ng-repeat="(prokey,proMd5) in item.failed_to_add_to_cart track by $index">
                                        <div class="product-image mini">

                                            <div class="p_image_innner">

                                                <img ng-src="{{proMd5.image}}" title="{{proMd5.title}}  by {{item.info.name}}">
                                                <div class="rateit">
                                                    <div class="rateis">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <a class="quick-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#quick-popup" ng-click="set_current_product_pro(proMd5,item,prokey,wsitekey)">+</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="caption"><a ng-click="menuShopApi('',item.info.name)">{{item.info.name}}</a></div> 
                                    </div>

                               </div> 

                            </div>
                          </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Angular flex slider attempt to solve inside partial

```
 <div class="recent_summary clearfix">
                <h2>RECENTLY VIEWED</h2>






                <div class="nav_carousel">
                    <div class="carousel mini_thumb_slider">

                        <ul class="stage_nav">

                          <li ng-repeat="arrObj in recentItems">
                            <div ng-repeat="arrItem in arrObj.timestamp track by $index">
                                <div ng-repeat="(wsitekey,item) in arrItem.sites track by $index">






                                     <flex-slider flex-slide="proMd5 in item.add_to_cart track by $index">
                                      <li>
                                      <div class="product-image mini">
                                            <div class="p_image_innner">
                                                <img ng-src="{{proMd5.image}}" title="{{proMd5.title}}  by {{item.info.name}}">
                                                <div class="rateit">
                                                    <div class="rateis">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <a class="quick-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#quick-popup" ng-click="set_current_product_pro(proMd5,item,prokey,wsitekey)">+</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="caption"><a ng-click="menuShopApi('',item.info.name)">{{item.info.name}}</a></div>
                                       </li> 
                                  </flex-slider>


                                    <div ng-repeat="(prokey,proMd5) in item.failed_to_add_to_cart track by $index">
                                        <div class="product-image mini">

                                            <div class="p_image_innner">

                                                <img ng-src="{{proMd5.image}}" title="{{proMd5.title}}  by {{item.info.name}}">
                                                <div class="rateit">
                                                    <div class="rateis">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <a class="quick-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#quick-popup" ng-click="set_current_product_pro(proMd5,item,prokey,wsitekey)">+</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="caption"><a ng-click="menuShopApi('',item.info.name)">{{item.info.name}}</a></div> 
                                    </div>

                               </div> 

                            </div>
                          </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

used scripts

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.2.2/flexslider.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.2.2/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/wilsonwc/angular-flexslider/master/angular-flexslider.js"></script>
```

Comment: With just this information we can't help you. Can you show some code?

Comment: updated the question with sample code

Comment: Are u sure that proMd5 is filled with data and that proMd5.image does exist?

Comment: @Rajib have you fixed this issue

Comment: First of all, you system need to know list of images which will put together inside slider, before it initialize the slider. for this purpose, after receiving data from database, you need to use a call back method to initialize slider. or you can wait for 1 second to initialize slider; by this time you will get the list of images from database. The problems happen because it initialize the slider before getting data from database

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexsilder without Angular and try this code:

```
var slider = $('#slider').data('flexslider');
slider.addSlide(obj, position);
```

or

```
$('#slider').flexslider('addSlide', obj[, position]);
```

Because HTML will be rendering after Flexsilder;